# Split string using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am new to JavaScript. I have a variable:

```
var externalClientDataBody = {"hotelCodes":"CUNMXSAKU_3d,CUNMXMAYA_4d"};
```

I want to split it on delimeter "_". I want my output to look like this:

```
var externalClientDataBody = {"hotelCodes":"CUNMXSAKU,CUNMXMAYA"};
```

I can ignore `"_3d _4d"` and want to get my string comma separated like `"CUNMXSAKU,CUNMXMAYA"`. Is there any way to do this using RegExp?

Comment: Are there always just two things in the list, or could it be more?

Comment: You've said "split," but you're not doing any splitting in the above, you're just removing `_3d` and `_4d` from the *one* string.

Comment: @Anders Could me more

Comment: You can also use `'CUNMXSAKU_3d'.match(/([^_]+)/)[1]` to extract all the characters before `_`.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to remove the `_` and anything following it through the end of the word, you can do it by matching `_` followed by "word" characters (`\w`) and replacing with `""`:

```
str = str.replace(/_\w+/g, '');
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var externalClientDataBody = {"hotelCodes":"CUNMXSAKU_3d,CUNMXMAYA_4d"};
externalClientDataBody.hotelCodes = externalClientDataBody.hotelCodes.replace(/_\w+/g, '');
snippet.log(externalClientDataBody.hotelCodes);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var regex = new RegExp('(^[^_]+)')
var input = 'dasddffsdff_d3';
var result = regex.exec(input);
//result = 'dasddffsdff'
```

[RegExr link](http://regexr.com/3btic)

Comment: Result will not be as shown with the above. It will be an array with two entries, `["dasddffsdff", "dasddffsdff"]`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I thought you would use it in a loop.

Comment: If you're going to say "result =" it should be correct. Moreover, `.exec` is the wrong tool for this job.